# ASP .NET 5 MVC 6 - Dropdown List Helper not displaying anymore since beta 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

The solution is probably quite simple here but somehow I can't figure out what to change...

I had a custom Html helper displaying a dropdown list on my view. Everything just worked fine until beta6 but since beta7, all I get instead of my dropdown is an object name :

**Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering.TagBuilder**

Here is the custom helper (simplified) to help to see how it works :

```
public static HtmlString DisplayComboboxFor<TModel, TResult>(
    this IHtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> propertyExpression,
    string idDropDown,
    SelectList selectList,
    bool withFormGroup = true,
    string colMdLabel = "col-md-2",
    string colMdInput = "col-md-10",
    string updateMethodDataBind = null,
    string selectMethodDataBind = null)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    // Getting usual information
    var property = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(propertyExpression);
    var displayName = MetadataProperty.GetDisplayName(propertyExpression);
    var errorMessage = MetadataProperty.GetRequiredErrorMessage(propertyExpression);
```

(...)

```
    // Generating component
    if(withFormGroup)
        builder.AppendLine("<div class=\"form-group\">");

    builder.AppendLine($"   <label class=\"{colMdLabel} control-label\" for=\"{property}\">{displayName}</label>");
    builder.AppendLine($"    <div class=\"{colMdInput}\">");
    builder.AppendLine(helper.DropDownList(idDropDown, selectList, new { data_bind = dataBind }).ToString());
    builder.AppendLine("    </div>");

    if (withFormGroup)
        builder.AppendLine("</div>");

    return new HtmlString(builder.ToString());
}
```

And a Razor view example :

```
 @Html.DisplayComboboxFor(model => model.Type, "typeSession", new SelectList(Model.AllTypeSession, "Id", "Valeur"), withFormGroup: false, colMdLabel: "col-md-2", colMdInput: "col-md-3")
```

The problem comes from helper.DropDownList since the rest of the Html is correclty written.

What should I change to get this dropdown list to display its Html content and not its object name ?

(Needless to say removing the ToString() didn't help with the changes I tried)